# Sum rows that match a condition and the others that dont in the same query

Tags: sql, count, nested, sum

I am trying to summarize in a table all the rows that match a condition as OpenOrder and the ones that dont. 
For now, I have a query that shows all the conditions

```
    select count(fk_OrderType)OrderCount, OrderName
from TrainingOrders group by fk_ActionTrainingType
```

This query shows a table with:

```
OrderName  OrderCount
A            10
B            5
C            7
D            3
```

What I want is this:

```
OrderName   ORderCount
A             10
E             15 (B+C+D)
```

I tried this

```
select sum(case when fk_OrderType= 45175 then 1 else 0 end) OpenOrder,
  sum(case when fk_OrderType<> 45175 then 1 else 0 end) NoOpenOrder
from TrainingOrders
```

But the result is not what Iam looking for. Someone tall me that I have to use a nested query, but I dont know how to do it.
Please, any light in this subject will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've done what you tried in Oracle, and it worked for me.  What did you get, and  what had you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your time and sorry the lack of details or clarification in my question. I already solved the problem using a pivot table following the example in https://www.sqlshack.com/es/multiples-opciones-para-transponer-filas-en-columnas/

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   select JobName,count(fk_OrderType)OrderCount, OrderName
from TrainingOrders group by fk_ActionTrainingType 
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(sum([OrderCount]) FOR [OrderName] IN([A],
                                                         [B],
                                                         [C],
                                                         [D],
                                                         [E])) AS PivotTable 
order by JobName;
```

This way I got the results that I was looking for.